# Shutting down 2009 MacBook Pro with new install of 10.7.5, results in restarting?

Tags: macbook-pro

I've just installed a new 500GB hard drive in a 2009 MacBook Pro and then cloned a clean install of OS X 10.7 on to the new drive.

I then updated to 10.7.5, and when I shut the MacBook Pro down the machine just restarts.

Any solutions anyone?

Answer (score 1):

Based off the replies in the comments, this is what I suggest doing:

In terminal, type the following command:

> cd /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/
>
> sudo rm com.apple.PowerManagement.plist
>
> sudo rm com.apple.AutoWake.plist

(Do the "rm" commands separately). Note: com.apple.AutoWake.plist might not exist. Then, shut down your mac, if it re-starts, just shut it down again and *hopefully* everything will be ok.

I hope this works.

[Source Details](https://discussions.apple.com/message/10465608?messageID=10465608#10465608?messageID=10465608)